# ATMega8 get too hot when connect AVCC pin to VCC!

Tags: atmega

My ATMega8 gets too hot when I connect the AVCC pin to VCC, either I use a filter or not (I do use ADC). Why?? Anyone got the same proplem? I use a 7905 regulator to create 5V for the MCU, and it also gets hot right after I connect the AVCC pin (before that it only warm up a little). Please help! I burned out a ATmega8!

[image]

Comment: Please add a schematic describing how you have connected everything. Also, do you mean 7**9**05 or 7**8**05? A 7905 is a negative voltage regulator.

Comment: there is nothing special on my circuit, just the Atmega8 alone, with a 14.4756MHz xtal and two 20pF capacitor for the external oscillator. That's all. And when I connect the AVCC pin to VCC, it gets hot really fast!
And the regulator is 7905, not 7805. Is that the problem?

Comment: You really need to include a schematic. And yes, unless you've wired it very particularly, you should not be using a 7905. What makes you think a 7905 is appropriate?

Comment: In all likelihood you've picked the wrong regulator and as a result put your full supply voltage into the ATMega and fried it. Always test your power supply rails before connecting to anything!

Comment: Your schematic is wrong - I say that simply because you have connected to the ATMega VCC and GND pins together in the schematic which would result in no power to or heating of the chip. Also the input to the regulator is GND and there is no other power supply marked on. Please correct the schematic to show *what you actually have connected*

Comment: sorry Tom, I updated a new pic =)
using 7905 regulator is must for my project. But I also tried a 7805, still hot. If I disconnect the AVCC pin, it works just fine, both ICs are cool. But if I reconnect the AVCC pin, in just one or two seconds I can't touch them!

Comment: What is your input voltage? Why are you using a negative voltage regulator?

Comment: It looks wrong... however posting a good photo of the circuit may help.. also check the requirement for the 7905, it's either a typo or some one is testing your ability to find the non-standard solution or the deliberate error.

Comment: **The regulator GND pin is the ground reference, even in a negative voltage system. So your "VCC" net is really ground return.** (This makes your schematic difficult to review and understand.) The ATmega8 VCC pin = LM7905 GND = system ground, and ATmega8 GND pin = system -5V rail from LM7905 OUT pin. Be careful with your logic levels, ATmega8 is referenced to its GND pin (the -5V rail). How is external power connected? Do you have e.g. 9V battery connection, (+) on LM7905 GND pin and (-) on LM7905 IN pin?

Comment: ok guys, my circuit works fine, so there are no problem about the schematic. The problem is the MCU gets hot when I connect the AVCC pin to the VCC pin, even if I use the 7805 regulator with a 9V battery or a 12V Adapter, or a USB port for power supply. All make the same result. So I think the problem here is the Atmega8. if I don't connect the AVCC pin then everything are normal, the ATmega8 is cool and the regulator just warm up a little. I think the build-in ADC system in the ATmega8 draws so much current!

Comment: It's not the ADC. It normal to connect vcc and avcc on this processor and it doesn't get hot at all. The schematic around IC1 is very confusing. The vcc net is attached to gnd pin. This can't be the actual circuit. Where is your power source attached?

Answer (score 1):

The circuit would work almost as-is with another blocking cap at the input of the 7905, but the first change will most likely introduce another GND reference and thus a short via the ESD diodes in the pins.

Note that the circuit is missing the ISP connector which is more likely connected in a debugging environment. This could introduce the above GND/Earth connection which can fry the chip.